# How to read facebook FriendsList using PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created Facebook app from developers.facebook.com. I have App ID and App Secret.

I given following permissions:

```
read_stream, manage_friendlists, user_friends
```

I used following code to read my facebook id and name:

```
$userdetails = file_get_contents(
"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me?fields=id,name&access_token=".$access_token);
```

I got id and name in JSON format.`{"id":"my_id","name":"Sathish Kumar"}`

I used following code for get friendslist

`$userdetails = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me?fields=id,name,friends&access_token=".$access_token);`

But, I got Warning message

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me?fields=id,name,friends&access_token=my_access_token) 

[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

How to get friends list using facebook api?

Comment: graph api has some methods, try them https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends

Comment: i fixed the second code, you posted the same one twice. check out my answer, it´s 100% correct.

Comment: Hi Luschn, I added "friends" in field, check this fields=id,name,friends. My problem is to get friends list.

Answer (score 0):

The correct endpoint would be `/me/friends`, you need to make another API call for that. I´d highly recommend using CURL for that instead of `file_get_contents`.

Keep in mind that you will only get friends already using the App, see changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score 0):

This code work fine for me. Check your access token is valid

```
$userdetails = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me?fields=id,name&access_token=".$access_token);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. Above code is working for me, but I need to get my friendslist. How do I get my friendslist?

Comment: $userdetails = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me?fields=id,name,friends&access_token=".$access_token);

use friends field which return all friends list in an array

OUTPUT:-
{
   "id": "ID of logged in user",
   "name": "logged in username",
   "friends": {
      "data": [
      ],
      "summary": {
         "total_count": 0
      }
   }
}

Comment: I tried same code. But I got warning message. I already mentioned in my question. "failed to open stream"

Comment: It is because the default timeout for socket is 60 seconds. In slow net connection this error will occur most commonly use the following code at top after the php open tag. This code will set the default timeout of the socket to 15 min from 1 min.

ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 900);

And also change the php file execution time to unlimited

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

This will fix your problem